Oracle APEX 24.1: Create workflow task, which has to be approved but all users with specific role, before the process resumes
As the topic states, I need to be able to create tasks that must be approved by an unspecified number of users. I have successfully created a task definition which creates as many apex_approval tasks as necessary (by using create action, I loop through all the proper users and create the new instance of task for each of them - in pl/sql code).
I also know how to write an SQL select statement for a "switch (workflow)" activity to check if all the created tasks are already completed. All tasks have a workflow_id parameter, so I can identify which tasks need to be completed.
However, I am struggling with how to design/configure the workflow to use all of the above without actively waiting or periodically checking if all tasks are completed. I am conscious of the disk space that could be taken up by logs in such a solution.
Here's what I’ve tried so far:

Suspending the workflow after all tasks were created. I was planning to check, after each task completion event, if all related tasks are completed and then resume the workflow.
However, the apex_workflow.suspend procedure checks the current user privileges and indicates that only a business admin can suspend the workflow.
Other ideas: I've experimented with several other approaches, but none have worked so far.

My goal is to have the workflow wait for all tasks to be completed without generating excessive log entries or requiring continuous checks.
Any ideas or suggestions from the community would be greatly appreciated!

A process plugin could help you. See this post.
